# How can I create a good panel for displaying rectangles in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am a not very good at C# yet so bear with me,
I am trying to create a program that can edit pictures of small sizes (16x16, 32x32, etc...), specifically Minecraft texture files. I need to create a drawing surface where I can display rectangles on. I want to use WPF rectangles because they are working for me so far. I tried putting them on a WPF Grid panel but creating a good size grid panel with 1 pixel wide rows and columns takes about thirty seconds and that's quite a lot of time. Any ideas are helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm getting the feel that your direction might not be the most efficient.
Of course, it's quite possible to convert an image into a lot of rectangles, but it's really not efficient once you have a lot of pixels. (32x32 = 1024 rectangles.)

So, instead of going along with WPF rectangles, like you want to, I would urge you to reconsider. Instead, try to work with [WriteableBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

From your vague description, I assume you are writing a paint like program, where the user can select a color and draw with the mouse on the texture with that color. By binding the WriteableBitmap up to an Image tag, and adding an event listener to the MouseMove event, you can get the mouse position, and whether the left/right mouse button is pressed or not. Combine that with some math involving the x position and the ActualWidth, and the y position and ActualHeight, of the Image, you can find the pixel the mouse is over, and set the color of that pixel.

So basically, Rectangles are not your best bet. Especially if you try to make a 32x32 grid to contain them. Use WriteableBitmap.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using something more lightweight like [`DrawingVisuals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742254.aspx). Alternatively if you really just want to display the textures you can preprocess them and display the result as a normal `Image`.